# Kotlin property not initialized, but why?

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlin-dsl

We're writing an internal DSL in Kotlin. Then we use it from our Java code. We see that the objects defined in the DSL are not yet available. Hence the question: Why is the package property not initialized?

Simplified the situation is thus:

```
val myObject = dsl {
    ...
}
```

And the DSL:

```
class Dsl() {
    companion object {
        val stored = mutableListOf<Dsl>()

        fun add(added: Dsl) {
            stored += added
        }
    }
}

fun dsl(init: Dsl.() -> Unit) {
    val dsl = Dsl()
    dsl.init()
    Dsl.add(dsl) // Intentional side effect to simplify DSL definition
}
```

Using the DSL from Java:

```
public class ExpectMyObject {
    @Test
    public void testMyObjectLoaded() {
        Assert.assertEquals(1, Dsl.Companion.getStored().size)
    }
}
```

I expected the package property to be initialized when starting the JVM. But the test fails. What am I overlooking?

Comment: try change val myObject to var

Comment: I tried that, but it made no difference. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to refer to *something* defined in same the file as `val myObject`, directly or indirectly, from your test. Otherwise its generated class won't get loaded. E.g.

```
@Test
public void testMyObjectLoaded() {
    your.package.FileNameKt.getMyObject();
    Assert.assertEquals(1, Dsl.Companion.getStored().size);
}
```

Comment: Hmmm. That limits the usability of the DSL. I think it means I will use some reflection to discover the classes and make sure they're loaded. Thanks for explaining what happens.

Comment: Reflection was not the tool for the job. Instead I've used the ServiceLoader. Yes, that required wrapping the DSL in a new class that implements an interfase. So sad....